# ASP.NET forum app: obtaining the answer with most likes

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

We are building a forum type web application, and we are tring to make the answers with most likes (and most dislikes) look different. The Answer entity has a Reactions property (list of reactions) that include likes and dislikes (those are differentiated with a boolean property, true for like, false for dislike). Is there a way to obtain the answer with most likes, and the answer with most dislikes, with a LINQ query directly? or we have to make a method that solves it?

EDIT: I have only one entity "Reactions" That represents both Likes and Dislikes. The only difference between the two of them, is a boolean property set on true for likes, and false on dislikes

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to StakOverflow!, would you able to provide how data structure would look like where you record like and unlike?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the relevant parts of your `DbSet<...>`: Apparently you  have `Answers`, `Likes`, and `DisLikes`. What is the relation between them? Does one Answer have columns with the number of Likes / Dislikes? Are the Likes / Dislikes in a separate tables. Is there a One-to-many relation: every Answer has zero or  more Likes-with-comments? or Many-to-Many as in: Many Answers have many Reactors, which one Like or  Dislike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Based on Sajid's comment, the query was simplified:

Of course:

```
reactions.Where(liked => Liked.IsLike && (liked.id = 123)).Count()
```

or even

```
reactions.Count(liked => liked.IsLike && liked.id == 123)
```

Comment: you can simplify the query to : `reactions.Count(liked => liked.IsLike && liked.id == 123)` or without `ToList()` : `reactions.Where(liked => liked.IsLike && liked.id == 123).Count()`

Comment: @Sajid you are right, edited my answer accordingly. I've got rusty with .NET not working with it for a while.